# Find Mysqldump Execution Time?

Tags: linux, database, bash, mysql

I want to find how much it takes to run my `mysqldump`  and compare it with my I/O rate at the end of `mysqldump` command.

looking for someting like :

```
bash:> time .dumpscript
```

--and at the end he will calculate my I/O rate from starting point to finish point giving me something like :

```
Dumpsize  Time    I/O per sec
30 gb     30 min  5mb/sec
```

Thx all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `time` command in bash to see how long your command takes. This will give the execution time in seconds:

```bash
{ time -p ./dumpscript; } 2>&1 | tail -3 | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
```

Presumably you know the location of the dump file, so you can find the size of that with `stat`. Since you now know the size of the file, and the time it took to create it, you can calculate the I/O rate with some basic arithmetic.